# Bi-Directional has_and_belongs_to_many on a Single Model in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, has-and-belongs-to-many, has-many

I have User model and I want to create friendship between users. I've achieved this using has_and_belongs_to_many

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :friends, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: :friend_id
```

And I have table for this association:

```
create_table :users_users do |t|
  t.uuid :user_id, null: false
  t.uuid :friend_id, null: false
  t.timestamps
end
```

When I get friends via user.friends I need to have association where current user is in user_id column or friend_id. My current solution returns me only records where user is in friend_id table.

I have two solution for this:

1. Duplicate records [{user_id: 1, friend_id: 2}, {user_id: 2, friend_id: 1}]
2. Override user.friends method and return my custom query

Both solution are not elegant and optimal.

I've read [article](http://cobwwweb.com/bi-directional-has-and-belongs-to-many-on-a-single-model-in-rails) about it, but the solution from this article is very complicated.

Is there any other solutions for this problem? I'm using rails 5.

Answer (score 0):

> First of all, I rather use that article solution or one query to fetch
>   all records instead of this.

The active record way to do this is:

1. create `has_many` relation instead of `HABTM` relation
2. query `users_users` table to find all records that match `user_id=my_user.id` or `friend_id=my_user.id`
3. flatten the result
4. unique them
5. remove current user from array

so I suggest putting this method in User model:

```
def all_friends
    UserFriend.includes(:user, :friend).where("user_id=? OR friend_id=?", id , id).map {|rel| [rel.user, rel.friend] }.flatten.uniq{|u| u.id}.reject{|u| u.id == self.id}
end
```

`UserFriend` model:

```
class CreateUserFriends < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :user_friends do |t|
      t.belongs_to :user, foreign_key: true
      t.belongs_to :friend, foreign_key: 'friend_id', class: 'User'

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: The drawback with a method in contrast to associations and scopes is that in certain situations they're harder to re-use when using `merge` and related mechanisms.

Comment: @ma_il agree. I'm not a fan of this technique but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure that this will work but still wanted to give this to you to try it out before I get some much-needed sleep ;)
Specify a custom query method to your association:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :friends, -> {
  where("friend_id = :user_id OR user_id = :user_id", user_id: id)
}, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: friend_id
```

Comment: It will not work because rails use inner join for fetch these records and this query will be merged with original one.. Now query looks like this:
`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" INNER JOIN "users_users" ON "users"."id" = "users_users"."user_id" WHERE  "users_users"."friend_id" = $1 AND (friend_id = '96b232eb-43ea-4eaa-9f47-9eae0516fde2' OR user_id = '96b232eb-43ea-4eaa-9f47-9eae0516fde2') [["friend_id", "96b232eb-43ea-4eaa-9f47-9eae0516fde2"]]`

Comment: Well that can still be remedied by explicitly adding the join table name to the query.